# Prevent an app from cracking in-app billing

Tags: java, c#, android, c++, in-app-billing

I'm developing some **standalone** games but not online ones and really want to include **in-app purchases** for some items. I'm using Unity3D for **Android** platforms, so most of my code is written in C# and Java.

I know well there's **no way to protect** the code written in **C#** and **Java** from reverse engineering at all. Just in case, I searched for some in-app billing security guidelines but those didn't seem to be effective for standalone Android apps. If I was developing online games, then yes, I could try some ways to prevent from cracking, because the game can't be played without a server connection.
But that's not my case.

Even if I use super safe APIs in the world for server-side verification and revocability, there are always possibilities for crackers to decompile and modify the code to skip reaching the store or server and just return **true**.
Then they can pack it again as APK and play with no limitations. I also tried to write some important code in **unmanaged C++** and use them in C#, but I quit it soon, because I thought it's also easy for crackers to break the connections between C++ and C#.

I've already said to myself there's no real solution for this. That's why I've never tried to put the in-app billing system yet.

But still wonder if there is anyway to make crackers harder to change the code for in-app billing, aside from real basic skills such as obfuscation.

Comment: Even if you find a maintainable way to "make it harder for crackers", it is a race you, and nobody else will ever win, in whichever language. The only way for standalone applications to be "safe" against crackers is when it takes too much effort to crack it before the next version ( which has wanted features, thus the old version is not desirable anymore ) appears. Only a few applications in the world have this nature, and I doubt your game is one of them.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with Slyps. Your time is far better spent writing great games than trying to beat that tiny percentage of people who might want to crack your code. The vast majority will get your games from an app store and pay as and when they should. Those few who do hack to get your stuff for free probably wouldn't have paid anyway and aren't worth your time. Just obfuscate your code when you build the apk and leave it at that.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this is it's a lot easier than developers think. I googled and followed the steps to decompile my APK. Just unzip and use some tools then there source files are as exactly I wrote. And I saw even little kids were doing these even though they didn't understand the code. I don't know much about iphones, but because Android and Unity3D use IL, it's easier than iphone apps to be cracked. I also know some developers whose games cracked and published in China. The crackers just changed the language to Chinese.

Comment: You may not know the name of the games but cracked. Android games are not like PC games, it's not like you think. But I agree with both of you. In the countries like the US, there are still many people pay for games.